# White dots in ListControurPlot

Tags: plotting

I am doing a ListContourPlot of my data (shown here)[image: plot], but even tho I use PlotRange->All and the density of data is the same everywhere there still are some white dots in the plot. I know for a fact that they have nothing to do with my data, bc when I run the ListContourPlot again with the exact same data and options the dots are still there, but in a different place. Do u have any idea what might be causing them?[image: white dots]

Comment: Try option PlotPoints...

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code.